# Longest increasing subsequence

Tags: c

The task is to find the length of the longest subsequence in a given array of integers such that all elements of the subsequence are sorted in ascending order. For example, the length of the LIS for { 15, 27, 14, 38, 26, 55, 46, 65, 85 } is 6 and the longest increasing subsequence is {15, 27, 38, 55, 65, 85}.

Following is the code I wrote. I am not sure if my logic is fine but the code fails to run properly. If I try to input the following test case

9
15
27
14

The program stops reading the values after 14 and gives me the output 2. It should read 9 values but the code is reading only 3 values. I have checked my code several times but unfortunately, I am unable to spot the error.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int N,max_val,i,j,k,l=1;
    int a[100000], track[100000];
    track[0]=0;
    max_val=1;
    scanf("%d",&N);
    for(i=0;i<N;++i)
    {
        printf("x");
        scanf(" %d",&a[i]);
        if(i!=0)
        {
            for(j=0;j<l;++j)
            {
                if(a[i]>a[track[j]])
                {
                    max_val++;
                    track[0]=i;
                    l=1;
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    track[l]=i;
                    l++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    printf("%d",max_val);
    return 0;
}
```

Help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: @Rizier123 Have you english it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/20314420/971127

Comment: @BLUEPIXY: I am not looking for a solution, I am more interested in knowing what is wrong with my code. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, nicely convoluted. You have undefined behavior here, and the way it expresses itself is instructive. The general problem is that

```
            if(a[i]>a[track[j]])  // <-- when i == 2, this first is false with
            {                     //     your input
                max_val++;
                track[0]=i;
                l=1;
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                track[l]=i;       // <-- and you end up here, where you write 
                l++;              //     into track[l] and increase l.
            }
```

After `l` is increased, you go back to the loop

```
for(j=0;j<l;++j)
```

Here `j` is increased, but since `l` has also increased, the condition is never (except not really, see below) false, and the loop continues. From this point on, the condition

```
a[i]>a[track[j]]
```

is always false, because you keep comparing the same two numbers, so `l` is incremented every turn, and this just keeps happening.

This goes on until `track` is full with twos (because `i` remains `2`). In fact, it goes on *after* `track` is full, writing into whatever happens to lie behind `track` in memory. What this is is not defined in the C language standard; for me this happens to be first `a`, then `N`, `max_val` and so forth in order of declaration (found that out with a debugger, a tool I encourage you to look into). YMMV. So, for me, `a` is also filled, and then `N` is overwritten with `2`, `max_val` etc. are also overwritten with `2`, then `l` is overwritten with `2`, and only then does the loop end. And then you go back to

```
for(i=0;i<N;++i)
```

...where now `N` is `2` and `i` is just being incremented to `3`. Then the loop ends, and then the program ends.

Perhaps needless to say, this is not behavior you can depend upon. The compiler doesn't have to arrange the stack variables in this order, and an optimising compiler can even generate code that doesn't hold certain variables in memory (or at all). But that is what happens.